# Frank Cucumber failing for external libraries

Tags: ios, xcode, cucumber, frank

In my xcode project, I have included two external libraries, DTCoreText and GMGridView. I also have my own created submodules in the project

When I execute. "frank build", I have observed that, the "build" folder is created for each submodules (created by me) and the main project. However, the "build" folder is not created for the above two projects, that I have included in my main project.

Finally, the build fails with

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/prabodh.prakash/Documents/xcode_workspace/<Project Name>/GMGridView/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGMGridView.a'

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/prabodh.prakash/Documents/xcode_workspace/<Project Name>/DTCoreText/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/libDTCoreText.a'
```

Please help. Let me know, if any other information is required for it.